# appfabric composite model

Tags: azure

I want to develop an application using **appfabric** composite application/model but i was unable to find any latest updates on it. Also very little help related to it is present on web thus creating a confusion that whether this feature is continued after **June CTP 2011** or not ?

Is there any update going to be available in future release?

Also I have installed windows **azure toolkit 1.7** and after that **azure appfabric sdk1.5** but in visual studio project templates I cannot find any template for **appfabric** as shown in some videos.

What additional installables will I require ?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Azure, word "App Fabric" is not longer used, instead all the services which were part of "Windows Azure App Fabric *" are named completely different (Service bus, ACS, Cache * etc) specific to their objective. That why you do not see any latest documentation specific to "App Fabric" in Windows Azure. Now when App Fabric term is used specific to Windows Server specific service model.

That's another reason when you installed Windows Azure SDK 1.7 you did not see any thing specific to App Fabric at all.

I am not sure how much it will apply but you sure can take a look at "[Building Hybrid Applications in the Cloud on Windows Azure - eBook](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30325&ocid=aff-n-we-loc--ITPRO40886)"  and see if that will help you.